# Vim use different config or shell enviroment variable when spawning new terminal

Tags: linux, shell, vim, terminal

Ok, so lets say I spawned a new terminal in vim using :terminal and I want to immediately have a shell enviroment with different/additional  enviroment variables within that new terminal window without typing for example VAR="something". How do i do that?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: well i tryed to bind an f key to spawn a new terminal window and typeout:

MANPAGER="sh -c 'col -bx | bat --theme=Solarized\ \(light\) -l man -p'"

so i wrote this in my vimrc:

Autocmd FileType python map <buffer> <F2> :botright terminal<CR>MANPAGER="sh -c 'col -bx | bat --theme=Solarized\ \(light\) -l man -p'";clean;python3<C-\><C-n>:resize 10<CR>i
none of this works unfortunalty. P.S sorry, this is hard to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set an environment variable in vim and then open a terminal, which will inherit all environment variables from vim.

```
let $VAR="something"
terminal
```

In terminal, you can check it by `echo $VAR`

Comment: yea thats it. i tried using let before but i did it with "let VAR" insted of "let $VAR". thanks for answer, tho i dont really understand why someone downvoted my post. that really grinds my gears |:   oh also can you explain what that $ in $VAR does exaclly?

Comment: *"without typing for example VAR="something""*

Comment: You can see `:help let-$`. It means setting an environment variable, while `let` sets an internal variable for vim.